# What are the header files in visual studio beginging with letter 'x' or 'xx'?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, header-files

When clicking on "external dependencies" in visual studio there are some headers beginning with

> X...

or

> XX...

[image]

what are those headers?

Comment: What do they look like when you open them?

Comment: They would have been .cpp files, if only you had a C++ compiler that supports exportable templates.  You're not alone.

Comment: @John, a bunch of preprocessor from MS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are internal implementation headers, they contain implementation details and get included by the headers that form the public interface of the Standard Library.

You should not include them directly from your code.